# Expand input size with content in React native Expo

Tags: react-native, expo

I have an input used to enter an amount, and a currency symbol next to it like that :

0 €

All two are centered in the screen (using a parent container with a width: "100%").

The problem is that when the user enters an amount, the currency symbol does not move and the amount expands from right to left.

**What I want to achieve** is to "push" the currency symbol to the right when the user enters an amount, to keep all the elements centered.

**I tried** to do this using a useRef to get the default width of the input and try to increase it when the amount changes.

I successfuly got the width value, but could not increase it.

Maybe there is another solution to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

The quick solution I figured out is to center those elements, the input and  the currency symbol, by setting the `justifyContent` style property of the parent element of these elements to center, I also used set the `flexDirection` property of the parent element as `row`

```
import { Text, TextInput, View } from "react-native";

export default function App() {
    return (
        <View>
            <View style={{flexDirection: "row", justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center"}} >
                <TextInput style={{textAlign: "right"}} defaultValue={"0"} />
                <Text>€</Text>
            </View>
        </View>
    )
}
```

That worked for me 
Hope it helps :), by the way it's my first stack overflow answer

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I found another solution which works.

I use a Text in absolute position behind the input, and make the input transparent.
With that trick, when the user enters an amount it is invisible in the input but we see the text behind and the currency symbol move to the right when typing :)